# Convert JsonObject into 'Node' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a json object.

```
{
    "aaa": {
        "aa": {
            "xxx": {
                "xxxx": {}
            }
        },
        "ab": {
            "xxx": {},
            "xxxx": {
                "xxxx": {}
            },
            "yyy": {
                "yyyy": {},
                "zzzz": {},
                "kkkk": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "bbb": {
        "": {}
    }
}
```

In order to use react-checkbox-tree,
I have to convert this object into node type.

```
 const nodes = [{value: 'mars', label: 'Mars',children: [
            { value: 'phobos', label: 'Phobos' },
            { value: 'deimos', label: 'Deimos' },
        ],
    }]`
```

I have tried multiple recursive functions that suggested from stackoverflow,
I couldn't find solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you for  your help. Though it doesn't work.  I got an error message saying 'push is not a function' I am finding solution now.

Comment: i put a working example for this reason. check it how it works. thnx

Comment: it works here, but I am wonder how it works. I use typescript so there's type issue and also,  const obj = { value: item, label: item } has no element named 'children' but it managed to assined obj.children = [].

Comment: cant help you further to be honest if you dont provide extra info! dont forget to accept answer. thnx!

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this recursive snippet.
Start with an empty array and for each property of the current object, create a new value/label object and insert it into the array.
If the property is an object, then create a new property inside that object called `children` and continue recursively

```js
const a = {
    "aaa": {
        "aa": {
            "xxx": {
                "xxxx": {}
            }
        },
        "ab": {
            "xxx": {},
            "xxxx": {
                "xxxx": {}
            },
            "yyy": {
                "yyyy": {},
                "zzzz": {},
                "kkkk": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "bbb": {
        "": {}
    }
}

const nodes = []

function buildNodesArray(jsonObject, children) {
  Object.keys(jsonObject).forEach((item) => {
    const obj = { value: item, label: item }
    children.push(obj)
  
    if (typeof jsonObject[item] === 'object' && jsonObject[item] !== null && Object.keys(jsonObject[item]).length > 0) {
      obj.children = []
      buildNodesArray(jsonObject[item], obj.children)
    }
  })
}

buildNodesArray(a, nodes)
console.log(nodes)
```